# Can this be approximated?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

The time complexity of finding k largest element using min-heap is given as 
`O(k + (n-k)log k)` as mentioned here [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/k-largestor-smallest-elements-in-an-array/) Can it be approximated to `O((n-k) log k)`?

Since `O(N+Nlog(k))=O(Nlog(k))` is above approximation also true ?

Comment: No you can't. Imagine *k* is very close (or equal) to *n*: then compare these expressions...

Answer (score 0):

No you can't simplify it like that. This can be shown with a few example values for *k* that are close to *n*:

### k = n

Now the complexity is defined as: *O(n + 0log n)* = *O(n)*. If you would have left out the first term of the sum, you would have ended of with *O(0)*, which obviously is wrong.

### k = n - 1

We get: *O((n-1) + 1log(n-1))* = *O(n + log(n))* = *O(n)*. Without the first term, you would get *O(log(n))*, which again is wrong.